# Match lines in two text files

Tags: python

i have two text files, first file is 40GB (data2) second is around 50MB (data1)
i want to check if any line in file1 have a match in file2 so I've written a python script (below) to do so, the process with this script takes too much time as it takes the line from file1 then it checks the whole file2 line by line.

```
for line in open("data1.txt","r"):
    for line2 in open("data2.txt","r"):
        if line==line2:
            print(line)
```

is there any way/code to make this fast? the script is running since 5 days and still didn't finish. is there a way also to show a % or current line number in process?

Comment: You have big files so it will take time, but other way you can do is, read data of `data1` (50MB) and store in list `file.readlines()` will return you list. Read data from `data2` and check its exists in `list`. This way you can avoid reading `data1` each time. Only once it will read.

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham im not sure if i understand you,, however, i already reversed the data1 by data2 so it check the big file (take line) then read the small file line by line..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use  a set and reverse the logic, checking if any line from the large data file is in the set of lines of f2 which is the smaller 50mb file:

```
with open("data1.txt", "r") as f1, open("data2.txt", "r") as f2:
    lines = set(f1) # efficient 0(1) lookups using a set
    for line in f2: # single pass over large file 
        if line in lines:
            print(line)
```

If you want the line number use enumerate:

```
with open("data1.txt", "r") as f1, open("data2.txt", "r") as f2:
        lines = set(f1) # efficient 0(1) lookups using a set
        for lined_no, line in enumerate(f2, 1): # single pass over large file      
            # print(line_no) # uncomment if you want to see every line number
            if line in lines:
                print(line,line_no)
```

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham set(f2) gave MemoryError so i've reversed the files to list the smaller file. im waiting the result now. is there a way also to show a % or current line number ?

Comment: @xhxx, I mixed up the data , I though data2 was the smaller. I updated the answer, if you want the line number we can use enumerate

Comment: no worries, yes i would like to see the current line number.

Comment: If you want to see every line number you will have to put the print line_no outside the if

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham thanks for the enumerate update, i meant not to print the line number of the matched line, i meant to make like a % process bar refreshing or a current scan line number.

Comment: Would `frozenset()` instead of `set()` make it faster?

Comment: @yhxx, you can just print the line_no outside the if as I suggested and you will see every line number, it may slow down the running time slightly  though having to print that many lines

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham if it will slow it down then no need for it, Thank you very much mate.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham update: using the enumerate code the speed is ~300k lines per minute looks very good to me as the big file have over 1.5 billion lines. Thanks

Comment: @xhxx, cool thanks for letting me know, should definitely be done before 5 days ;)

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham oh yes, now i used enumerate on my old script to test and see the speed difference, and im shocked the speed is around 1 line per 5 min ! THANK YOU!

Comment: No prob, I would avoid using the prints for every lines, a nicer way would be adding and `if line_no % 1000000 == 0: print(line_no)` so you get an update after every million lines

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham Great!! Thanks

Comment: @xhxx, try this code using multiprocessing, I have not used the module in a long time and not sure about everything is correct but might be worth experimenting with. http://pastebin.com/DvxBLxPf

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham yes i like to do experiments for speed, the code throws too multiple errors : http://pastebin.com/xktB8QGD , Thanks

Comment: ah ok you are on windoze, it was just an experiment. I will have a look at the docs and see what the story is